# How to align two columns that have empty spaces?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I am trying to align two columns one of which sometimes have empty spaces

I am using that code

```
#For the first column
awk '{print $9}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt | grep -oP ";\KName=[^;]+"

#For the second column
awk '{print $9}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt | cut -c4-14
```

The problem is that when I try to align them using the following code

```
names=`awk '{print $9}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt | grep -oP ";\KName=[^;]+" | 
uniq`

for pmz in `awk '{print $9}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt | cut -c4-14 | uniq`
do
        read -r
        echo "Symbols $pmz correspond to $REPLY"
done <<< "$names"
```

By the end lots of PMZ does not correspond to anything because some PMZ do not have names. That is what I have now as an output

```
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Slc6a18
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Slc6a18
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Shh
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Shh
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=SHH
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=SHH
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=SLC6A19
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=SLC6A19
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=cut14
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=cut14
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=CUTC
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=CUTC
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=Gtf3c2
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=Gtf3c2
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=Calhm2
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=Calhm2
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=Epb41l1
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=Epb41l1
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=EPB41L3
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=EPB41L3
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=Tti2
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=Tti2
```

and that is what I would like to see

```
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Slc6a18
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Slc6a18
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=Shh
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=Shh
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=SHH
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=SHH
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to 
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
```

This is the beginning of that PMZ file

```
##gff-version 3
#hide=gene
scaf_00001  maker   gene    3168    5340    .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0036570;Dbxref=InterPro:IPR000175,PANTHER:PTHR11616,PANTHER:PTHR11616:SF125,Pfam:PF00209,ProSiteProfiles:PS50267,SUPERFAMILY:SSF161070;Name=Slc6a18;desc=Sodium-dependent neutral amino acid transporter B(0)AT3 (Mus musculus);Ontology_term=GO:0005328,GO:0006836,GO:0016021
scaf_00001  maker   mRNA    3168    5340    .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0036570-RA;Parent=PMZ_0036570;_AED=0.21;_eAED=0.25;_QI=0|0|0|1|0|0|2|0|92;Dbxref=InterPro:IPR000175,PANTHER:PTHR11616,PANTHER:PTHR11616:SF125,Pfam:PF00209,ProSiteProfiles:PS50267,SUPERFAMILY:SSF161070;Name=Slc6a18;desc=Sodium-dependent neutral amino acid transporter B(0)AT3 (Mus musculus);Ontology_term=GO:0005328,GO:0006836,GO:0016021
scaf_00001  maker   exon    3168    3304    .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0036570-RA:1;Parent=PMZ_0036570-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 3168    3304    .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0036570-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0036570-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    5202    5340    .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0036570-RA:2;Parent=PMZ_0036570-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 5202    5340    .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0036570-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0036570-RA
scaf_00001  maker   gene    11116   13826   .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0041002;Dbxref=Gene3D:G3DSA:2.170.16.10,InterPro:IPR001657,InterPro:IPR001767,InterPro:IPR003586,InterPro:IPR028992,PANTHER:PTHR11889,PANTHER:PTHR11889:SF36,PRINTS:PR00632,Pfam:PF01079,SMART:SM00305,SUPERFAMILY:SSF51294;Name=Shh;desc=Sonic hedgehog protein (Mus musculus);Ontology_term=GO:0006508,GO:0007154,GO:0007275,GO:0008233
scaf_00001  maker   mRNA    11116   13826   .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA;Parent=PMZ_0041002;_AED=0.12;_eAED=0.20;_QI=0|0|0|0.66|1|1|3|0|228;Dbxref=Gene3D:G3DSA:2.170.16.10,InterPro:IPR001657,InterPro:IPR001767,InterPro:IPR003586,InterPro:IPR028992,PANTHER:PTHR11889,PANTHER:PTHR11889:SF36,PRINTS:PR00632,Pfam:PF01079,SMART:SM00305,SUPERFAMILY:SSF51294;Name=Shh;desc=Sonic hedgehog protein (Mus musculus);Ontology_term=GO:0006508,GO:0007154,GO:0007275,GO:0008233
scaf_00001  maker   exon    11116   11625   .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA:3;Parent=PMZ_0041002-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 11116   11625   .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0041002-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    11712   11858   .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA:2;Parent=PMZ_0041002-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 11712   11858   .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0041002-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    13797   13826   .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA:1;Parent=PMZ_0041002-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 13797   13826   .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0041002-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0041002-RA
scaf_00001  maker   gene    14712   18011   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0041003;Dbxref=Gene3D:G3DSA:2.170.16.10,InterPro:IPR001767,InterPro:IPR003587,InterPro:IPR028992,PANTHER:PTHR11889,Pfam:PF01079,SMART:SM00306,SUPERFAMILY:SSF51294;Name=SHH;desc=Sonic hedgehog protein (Cynops pyrrhogaster);Ontology_term=GO:0006508,GO:0008233
scaf_00001  maker   mRNA    14712   18011   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA;Parent=PMZ_0041003;_AED=1.00;_eAED=1.00;_QI=0|0|0|0|1|1|3|0|147;Dbxref=Gene3D:G3DSA:2.170.16.10,InterPro:IPR001767,InterPro:IPR003587,InterPro:IPR028992,PANTHER:PTHR11889,Pfam:PF01079,SMART:SM00306,SUPERFAMILY:SSF51294;Name=SHH;desc=Sonic hedgehog protein (Cynops pyrrhogaster);Ontology_term=GO:0006508,GO:0008233
scaf_00001  maker   exon    14712   14740   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA:1;Parent=PMZ_0041003-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 14712   14740   .   +   0   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0041003-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    15646   15988   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA:2;Parent=PMZ_0041003-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 15646   15988   .   +   1   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0041003-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    17940   18011   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA:3;Parent=PMZ_0041003-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 17940   18011   .   +   0   ID=PMZ_0041003-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0041003-RA
scaf_00001  maker   gene    90001   94433   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0036800;Dbxref=InterPro:IPR000175,PANTHER:PTHR11616,PANTHER:PTHR11616:SF109,Pfam:PF00209,Phobius:CYTOPLASMIC_DOMAIN,Phobius:NON_CYTOPLASMIC_DOMAIN,Phobius:TRANSMEMBRANE,ProSiteProfiles:PS50267,SUPERFAMILY:SSF161070;Name=SLC6A19;desc=Sodium-dependent neutral amino acid transporter B(0)AT1 (Homo sapiens);Ontology_term=GO:0005328,GO:0006836,GO:0016021
scaf_00001  maker   mRNA    90001   94433   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA;Parent=PMZ_0036800;_AED=0.34;_eAED=0.57;_QI=0|0.33|0|1|1|0.75|4|0|108;Dbxref=InterPro:IPR000175,PANTHER:PTHR11616,PANTHER:PTHR11616:SF109,Pfam:PF00209,Phobius:CYTOPLASMIC_DOMAIN,Phobius:NON_CYTOPLASMIC_DOMAIN,Phobius:TRANSMEMBRANE,ProSiteProfiles:PS50267,SUPERFAMILY:SSF161070;Name=SLC6A19;desc=Sodium-dependent neutral amino acid transporter B(0)AT1 (Homo sapiens);Ontology_term=GO:0005328,GO:0006836,GO:0016021
scaf_00001  maker   exon    90001   90020   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:1;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 90001   90020   .   +   0   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    90582   90683   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:2;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 90582   90683   .   +   1   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    92087   92195   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:3;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 92087   92195   .   +   1   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    94338   94433   .   +   .   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:4;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 94338   94433   .   +   0   ID=PMZ_0036800-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0036800-RA
scaf_00001  maker   gene    175288  205009  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056;Dbxref=Coils:Coil,Gene3D:G3DSA:3.40.50.300,InterPro:IPR003395,InterPro:IPR010935,InterPro:IPR027120,InterPro:IPR027417,PANTHER:PTHR18937,PANTHER:PTHR18937:SF9,Pfam:PF02463,Pfam:PF06470,SMART:SM00968,SUPERFAMILY:SSF52540,SUPERFAMILY:SSF75553;Name=cut14;desc=Structural maintenance of chromosomes protein 2 (Schizosaccharomyces pombe (strain 972 / ATCC 24843));Ontology_term=GO:0000796,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005694,GO:0007076,GO:0051276
scaf_00001  maker   mRNA    175288  205009  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA;Parent=PMZ_0033056;_AED=0.35;_eAED=0.38;_QI=215|0.38|0.42|1|0.61|0.73|19|0|858;_merge_warning=1;Dbxref=Coils:Coil,Gene3D:G3DSA:3.40.50.300,InterPro:IPR003395,InterPro:IPR010935,InterPro:IPR027120,InterPro:IPR027417,PANTHER:PTHR18937,PANTHER:PTHR18937:SF9,Pfam:PF02463,Pfam:PF06470,SMART:SM00968,SUPERFAMILY:SSF52540,SUPERFAMILY:SSF75553;Name=cut14;desc=Structural maintenance of chromosomes protein 2 (Schizosaccharomyces pombe (strain 972 / ATCC 24843));Ontology_term=GO:0000796,GO:0005515,GO:0005524,GO:0005694,GO:0007076,GO:0051276
scaf_00001  maker   exon    175288  175458  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:19;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 175288  175458  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    180207  180290  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:18;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 180207  180290  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    191270  191404  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:17;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 191270  191404  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    191733  191939  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:16;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 191733  191939  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    192070  192138  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:15;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 192070  192138  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    194765  194848  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:14;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 194765  194848  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    195325  195518  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:13;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 195325  195518  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    195773  195798  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:12;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 195773  195798  .   -   1   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    196705  196826  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:11;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 196705  196826  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    197035  197250  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:10;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 197035  197250  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    197585  197704  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:9;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 197585  197704  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    197939  198041  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:8;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 197939  198041  .   -   1   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    198658  198709  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:7;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 198658  198709  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    199737  199896  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:6;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 199737  199896  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    199982  200266  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:5;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 199982  200266  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    200738  200887  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:4;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 200738  200887  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    201232  201423  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:3;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 201232  201423  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    202615  202653  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:2;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 202615  202653  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    204627  205009  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:1;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 204627  204794  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   five_prime_UTR  204795  205009  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0033056-RA:five_prime_utr;Parent=PMZ_0033056-RA
scaf_00001  maker   gene    206906  245636  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065;Dbxref=Gene3D:G3DSA:3.20.20.380,Hamap:MF_00795,InterPro:IPR005627,InterPro:IPR023648,PANTHER:PTHR12598,Pfam:PF03932,SUPERFAMILY:SSF110395;Name=CUTC;desc=Copper homeostasis protein cutC homolog (Homo sapiens);Ontology_term=GO:0005507,GO:0055070
scaf_00001  maker   mRNA    206906  245636  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA;Parent=PMZ_0048065;_AED=0.17;_eAED=0.17;_QI=110|1|1|1|0|0|9|257|245;Dbxref=Gene3D:G3DSA:3.20.20.380,Hamap:MF_00795,InterPro:IPR005627,InterPro:IPR023648,PANTHER:PTHR12598,Pfam:PF03932,SUPERFAMILY:SSF110395;Name=CUTC;desc=Copper homeostasis protein cutC homolog (Homo sapiens);Ontology_term=GO:0005507,GO:0055070
scaf_00001  maker   exon    206906  207274  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:1;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   three_prime_UTR 206906  207162  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:three_prime_utr;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 207163  207274  .   -   1   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    210422  210527  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:2;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 210422  210527  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    212343  212370  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:3;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 212343  212370  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    216599  216732  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:4;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 216599  216732  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    217311  217346  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:5;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 217311  217346  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    219537  219746  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:6;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 219537  219746  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    236885  236944  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:7;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 236885  236944  .   -   2   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   exon    241653  241716  .   -   .   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:8;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
scaf_00001  maker   CDS 241653  241704  .   -   0   ID=PMZ_0048065-RA:cds;Parent=PMZ_0048065-RA
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include a sample of your original  `PMZ_genes.gff3.txt` file? I have a feeling it might be simpler to start from that than from your processed data

Comment: thank you, I made some edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$9==""{next}        # skip if $9 is empty
{
  id=substr($9,4,11)     # get the id
  name=""                # set empty name as default
  idx=index($9,"Name=")  # get index of `Name=`
  if (idx){              # if index is not zero
    name=substr($9,idx)  # substring name from idx
    sub(/;.*/,"",name)   # and remove `;` and everything after
  }
  print "Symbols "id" correspond to "name
}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt
```

Output:

```
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Slc6a18
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to Name=Slc6a18
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036570 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=Shh
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to Name=Shh
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041002 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=SHH
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to Name=SHH
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0041003 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to Name=SLC6A19
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to Name=SLC6A19
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0036800 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to Name=cut14
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to Name=cut14
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0033056 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to Name=CUTC
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to Name=CUTC
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
Symbols PMZ_0048065 correspond to
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` alternative

```
awk '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
  if ($i ~ /ID=PMZ_/) printf "Symbols %s correspond to ", substr($i,4);
    else if ($i ~ /Name=/) printf $i;}{i=NF;printf "\n";
}' <(sed "s/[;-]/ /g" file)
```